# This command is not available because no document is open while getting Active document

Tags: c#, vsto

```
try
{
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordObj = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application;
     Office.CustomXMLParts currClassification = WordObj.ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     //I am getting, This command is not available because no document is open. this error here.
}
```

When I am using above code, I am getting this error:

> This command is not available because no document is open.

Regards

Comment: And what's your problem? Something is unclear in the error message?

Comment: Nope actually a document is already open, I just need to fetch info stored in metadata of that document.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not creating a new instance, I am fetching the current active instance of the word in the first line.

Comment: I guess your document was not open... hmm

Comment: Obviously, as I was unaware with that scenario, so my code was generating the exception. So, I had posted that question and more importantly I was not trying to open New instance of word from my code, So solution you posted and deleted was of no use for me in which you told to add a new document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you are trying to access active document when there is no document open in word application so you are getting an error.
Your word application is open but no document is opened in it i.e. you are at home screen of word application as shown in image.

[image]

Try to use following code to check whether there are any open documents in your application and then access ActiveDocument

```
if(WordObj.Documents.Count >= 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how but adding a folder named "Desktop" in the below locations solved my issue.

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\